# ProgressBar does not respond on the UI unless an invoke

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have a strange case.
I have a combobox in my windows form application.
When selected index changed, it starts a background worker process to interact with progress bar.
My DoWork is like that :

```
private void backgroundWorkerProgressBar_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int campaignID = (int)e.Argument;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        CampaignEmailIndex.TryGetValue(campaignID, out subscribers); // This is a dictionary that keeps subscriber numbers. Subscriber number keeps growing while application works.
        backgroundWorkerProgressBar.ReportProgress(subscribers);
    }

}
```

My Progress_Changed is simple :

```
private void backgroundWorkerProgressBar_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;            
}
```

But this code does not work properly. Progress bar does not move in the application unless I change selected index of combobox.

But this code works in DoWork event handler. It changes the state of the progress bar and does not need me to select combobox index again.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
     backgroundWorkerProgressBar.ReportProgress(i);
}
```

When I debug the application, everything works properly, value is passed to progress changed event but it is not shown on UI. By the way CampaignEmailIndex and subsribers are global variables.

Thanks All.

Edited : 
The code that starts the background worker is :

```
private void cmbCampaignInPoolByID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int campaignID = (int)cmbCampaignInPoolByID.SelectedItem;
    DataTable dt = DatabaseManager.GetCampaignDetails(campaignID);

    subscribers = DatabaseManager.GetCampaignSubscribers(campaignID).Rows.Count;

    progressBarMailQueu.Maximum = subscribers;
    backgroundWorkerProgressBar.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorkerProgressBar.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorkerProgressBar_DoWork);
    backgroundWorkerProgressBar.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorkerProgressBar_ProgressChanged);
    backgroundWorkerProgressBar.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorkerProgressBar_RunWorkerCompleted);            
    backgroundWorkerProgressBar.RunWorkerAsync(campaignID);
```

}

Comment: Have you debugged what the value of "subscribers" is when you do ReportProgress(subscribers) ? If this is not a number between 0 and 100, your progressbar is going to get confused. It's up to you to clap this value between 0 and 100 (or whichever bounds your progressbar is set to) and ensure the values are reported in a proper manner (e.g. you don't want to feed it the value 50 followed by the value 0. You're also using TryGetValue - does TryGetValue actually succeed ?)

Comment: @nos - exactly what I was thinking - indeed a 'subscribers' amount which presumably doesn't have a maximum can't easily be turned into a percentage; since there is no real maximum (well apart from the world's population)

Comment: yes it succeeds, and the subscribers value is correct, as I know the max number of subscribers, i know the maximum of progress bar, so no cofusion there.

Comment: What's the code that starts the background worker?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to write your code:

```
    private void cb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bg.RunWorkerAsync(cb.SelectedIndex);
    }

    private void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int campaignID = (int)e.Argument;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            int subscribers = new Random().Next(0, 100);
            bg.ReportProgress(subscribers);
            Thread.Sleep(30);
        }
    }

    private void bg_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        pb.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

Look to *Thread.Sleep(30)*: it's used to be able to see something.
Everything works for me: the progressbar moves correctly during the for cycle.
**bg** is a BackgroungWorker with ReportProgress=true and **pb** is ProgressBar (0,100).
If you are sure that **subscribers is in range 0..pb.Max** that should work.

Comment: Thanks Marco, it did not work out for me. Progress bar still needs to select cb value again in order to take action. I am sure that it is in range. It is quite possible, there is an issue with the dictionary object. As I said, if you give a simple int value that i define locally, my code works properly also. But out parameter and dictionary confuses things. Thanks alot for your code .

Comment: @spagetticode Can you give us your source code to analyze?
ProgressBar is created from designer in main form or dynamically from backgroundworker?

Comment: I edited it Marcoi. It is created in the desingner and starting the process in the selectedIndexChanged Event